# Obtaining an expression/approximation for z in a function containing the normal cdf $\Phi(z)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, approximation

I have the following expression $$z=\alpha-\beta q$$
where $\alpha$, $\beta$ are known parameters and $q=1-F_X(z)$, where $X\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ [*footnote1]. I want to solve for $z$ and have struggled to isolate it.

I have tried playing with the algebra of some known approximations of $\Phi$ (e.g. wikipedia or [these](https://www.hrpub.org/download/20140305/MS7-13401470.pdf)), with no luck. Although I would prefer it, I don't *need* an exact answer, it would be enough to have a good approximation (e.g. to a couple decimal places $z \approx$...).

For an approximation, I unfortunately cannot assume that z is small.

Thanks for your time!

[*footnote1]: with $\mu= c(b-a)+da, \sigma^2 =e((b-a)^2+a^2)$, a combination of some known parameters

Comment: Just to be clear : could you write the expression of $q$ as a function of $\sigma$ and $\mu$ since apparently they are fixed values ?

Comment: Thank you @ClaudeLeibovici. Perhaps my comment on what the mean and variance are exactly only served to confuse matters. It is safe to assume $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are known.

Comment: (i.e. yes $F_X(z)$ and therefore $q$ could be expressed in terms of $z$ (the uncomfortable term to have inside), $\sigma$ and $\mu$)